# Where can the Tosafot of Rabbi Samson of Sens be found?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rishonim, tosfot

This might be quite a basic question, but there’s a passage from Rabbi Samson of Sens’s commentary on Mishnah Eduyot 1:5 that I’ve seen quoted in a few books eg [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=spbUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22this%20applies%20to%20the%20amoraim%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjty4eFk-biAhUit3EKHTD5DtYQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22this%20applies%20to%20the%20amoraim%22&f=false).

(Sometimes it’s quoted as being from Rabbi Samson’s Tosefta Sens or Tosefta Shantz, but always from Eduyot, which seems slightly odd since Eduyot is Mishnah rather than Gemara).

I can’t find this commentary anywhere, eg Shas, Hebrew Books, Responsa Project... Can anyone help nudge me in the right direction, even if it’s only available on paper would be helpful to have a title or some other information to help find it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tosafot Shants are printed in the margins of Eduyot in the standard Vilna edition of the Talmud (counterintuitively, it isn't usually printed in editions of the Mishna). You can read it online [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37970&pgnum=494). His commentary to tractates in [Zera'im](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14308&pgnum=327), [Middot](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37968&pgnum=850) and [Tahorot](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40053&pgnum=314) is also printed with the Talmud.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! (I didn't think of looking in a counterintuitive masechet.) Surprising that it's not on Responsa Project but then life is surprising...

Comment: BTW, the Rash on Middos is Rabeinu Shimayah, not the Rash MiShantz.

Comment: There are editions of the TOS santz on ketubot

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/home#gsc.tab=0      the first three

Answer (score -1):

Rash MiShantz commentary on Mishnah can be found (in certain Bavli Talmud) printed in Brachot (for Zeraim) and Niddah (for Tahorot). It can also be found in certain printings of Rambam's Mishnah commentary.

Comment: Thanks minhag but I think you misunderstood the question.